# What's the meaning of this whitespace in the inspector?

Tags: html, css

There is a grey line between two span "day_date" and "update_date", when I clicked the inspector, it said it is whitespace, what does it means by whitespace.
Since I wanna have the exact same result as the image showed below, and I thought that grey line was made with “border-right”...

My final goal is to produce that grey line with coding

[image]

P.S. here is the source code

```
<div id="t3-topbars" class="t3-topbars">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="t3-date col-xs-4 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
    <span class="day-date">Dec 16, 2019</span>              <span class="update-date">
                Last Updated 8:02 AM, Nov 26, 2019        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: it likely means that there were lines of whitespace between, so instead of showing those it just put the "whitespace" thing there. View the source instead of using the inspector to see.

Comment: Share code, not images

Comment: @Jhecht I dig into the source code but still can't get it, I have added the photo of the source code, thank you

Comment: Please @neverquit past your HTML markup here so we can reproduce this in our answers.

Comment: well, as you can see, between the `day-date` and `update-date` elements, there's a bunch of blank white space. Seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry it is my second time using stack overflow, I have just modified it

Comment: "_I still can't see how to implement it_" Implement what? If you don't want the whitespace (spaces/tabs/newlines etc.), remove them so that the close tag is immediately followed by the open tag.

Comment: the whitespace think is just the element inspector letting you know that there was whitespace between these two things, but that it is displaying them in the more commonly used tree structure. Not a whole lot to do about that

Comment: So all I have to do is just add whitespace between the two span and there will be a grey line? I got it thank you cause I wanna to exact same result with the image show above.

Answer (score 3):

This because of standard whitespaces.

form [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Whitespace):

> specifies 5 characters as the ASCII whitespace: U+0009 TAB, U+000A LF, U+000C FF, U+000D CR, and U+0020 SPACE. In text, they are treated as normal space characters and sequencial whitespaces are collapsed as a single space in many cases

for removing this [whitespace] from your site inspector. you must remove standard whitespaces like new lines.

and you can see: [DevTools now display white space text nodes in the DOM inspector](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this link is helpful [DevTools now display white space text nodes in the DOM inspector](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/)

You can create whitespace in the design using padding or margin around any tag